# OP_CHECKMULTISIG Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation

Tags: script, multi-signature

I am trying to spend a P2SH multi-signature output which I have created with [rust-bitcoin](https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-bitcoin) as follows:

```
let builder = Builder::new()
        .push_opcode(opcodes::all::OP_PUSHNUM_2)
        .push_key(&pub_a)
        .push_key(&pub_x)
        .push_opcode(opcodes::all::OP_PUSHNUM_2)
        .push_opcode(OP_CHECKMULTISIG);
Script::new_p2sh(&builder.into_script().script_hash())
```

For creating the scriptSig I have the following code:

```
let sig_a = secp.sign(&msg, &sk.key);
let sig_x = secp.sign(&msg, &x.key);
let sig_a_der = serialize_sig_der_with_sighash(&sig_a, SIGHASH_ALL);
let sig_x_der = serialize_sig_der_with_sighash(&sig_x, SIGHASH_ALL);
let lock_script_bytes: Vec<u8> = lock_script.to_bytes();
// Now we need to combine the original P2SH script and the actual redeem script
let fin_script = Builder::new()
    .push_opcode(opcodes::all::OP_PUSHBYTES_0) /// Needed because of and issue on OP_CHECKMULTISIG
    .push_slice(&sig_x_der)
    .push_slice(&sig_a_der)
    .push_slice(&lock_script_bytes)
    .into_script();
```

Now I have tested this on the testnet and am receiving

[image]

I have tried to debug this using [btcdeb](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/btcdeb) and am seeing the following stack before the OP_CHECKMULTISIG executes:

```
#0015 OP_CHECKMULTISIG
btcdeb> stack
<01>    02      (top)
<02>    02952453888ebcb21720aa81ef9c43ffdb3127b30c5e2d0f61c1c1550b7a29babf
<03>    03dcc4a286cab7209043e5658bfe6ef08adde7128ee5d9bf74862f27ff15f9d519
<04>    02
<05>    3045022100ae1fe1fb0b02586b012ff01be7835269e6079b85f089123ecaf6a482e0324ca602206d2236fd0d07e018097c19e2c9bb8d0b31e18cf51624275b36e596b1969ac3b901
<06>    3045022100bbf92e527688209bacb3e75501fdf1744a7e6e8cd2c922b499d7b40b8dff6260022045845247d1a1fe04aa1ab1866473acf06abc63d5ecdebe6dae0ff7be3200795f01
<07>
btcdeb> step
                <> POP  stack
                <> POP  stack
                <> POP  stack
                <> POP  stack
error: Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation
btcdeb>
```

Afterwards, the stack looks like this:

```
btcdeb> stack
<01>    3045022100ae1fe1fb0b02586b012ff01be7835269e6079b85f089123ecaf6a482e0324ca602206d2236fd0d07e018097c19e2c9bb8d0b31e18cf51624275b36e596b1969ac3b901                                       (top)
<02>    3045022100bbf92e527688209bacb3e75501fdf1744a7e6e8cd2c922b499d7b40b8dff6260022045845247d1a1fe04aa1ab1866473acf06abc63d5ecdebe6dae0ff7be3200795f01
<03>
```

The message for the signature is created as follows:

```
let sighash = tx.signature_hash(ix, &script_pubkey, SIGHASH_ALL.into());
println!("msg: {}", hex::encode(&sighash.as_ref()));
let msg = Message::from_slice(&sighash.as_ref())
    .unwrap();
```

which outputs `0312f22fd74e55216e51c2724051d8cf9c8833edc1596871fc357a71b3826634`.

It seems to me that something is still wrong structurally because after the `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` has been executed we see that both signatures are actually still on the stack and haven't been popped.

Comment: Usually problems like this are the result of constructing the message incorrectly. What is the data in `script_pubkey`? It needs to be the multisig script that you are using, not the actual scriptPubKey.

Comment: The data in script_pubkey when constructing the signature message is `OP_HASH160 <hash> O_EQUAL` so the scriptPubKey of the input spent. Do I understand correctly that this is incorrect and should actually be the script that is being executed (and wrapped in the P2SH)?

Comment: Yes. For P2SH, the script you should be using is the script being executed, i.e. the redeemScript.

Comment: @AndrewChow Wow, that fixed it! (well that and I also had the order of the signatures mixed up.) Thanks a lot for your help!